# Netgear A6210 (Mediatek MT7612U). & Ethernet Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 devices not found above kernel 5.4.0-42- LTS 20.04.2

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, realtek

Netgear A6210 (Mediatek MT7612U). & Ethernet Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 devices are not found after higher kernel 5.4.0-42 on LTS 20.04.2
Both devices work under 5.4.0-42-lowlatency
In the syslog under NetworkManager it should say ~:-
NetworkManager[729]:   [16127] device (enp24s0): ...
NetworkManager[729]:   [16127] device (wlxb0b98a580d83): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
NetworkManager[729]:   [16127] manager: (wlxb0b98a580d83): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device ..
NetworkManager[729]:   [16127] device (wlxb0b98a580d83): ...

Comment: I am not sure what the Netgear A6210 is using as its chipset driver, but I am using a RTL8168 in Kernel 5.8.0-41-generic just fine.  I installed it as `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` and it has been working just fine.  The r8169 that it detected before (which isn't the correct chipset anyway) was very flaky and needed a reset all the time.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-65

There is a fix released for this bug but I am not sure when a new kernel will have the fix, for now check in terminal `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled, then in terminal do

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/mt76.git
cd mt76
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp mt76x02-lib.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
```

Reboot, if after another kernel update it fails to work do

```
cd mt76
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp mt76x02-lib.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
```

Comment: I found the fix - install the extra modules - sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-65-generic

Comment: I already tried your make -C ... but it did not work

Comment: How do i remove the "dkms add ." - I also applied as per your help on the linux mint page

Comment: I would check `modinfo mt76x02-lib | grep intree` as if there is no result you are likely using my fix.  I am downloading the 5.4.0-66-generic kernel to see if the fix was finally included

Comment: OK modinfo mt76x02-lib | grep intree gives no result. So in my case I had no networking until I installed extra modules & is not a general fix

Comment: The extra modules should be dependency of the kernel, to remove the dkms, `sudo dkms remove mt76-5.4/1.0 --all`

Comment: The issue looks like it is fixed in 5.4.0-65 and newer

Comment: I will keep as is as It works. According to modinfo ... I am using your fix. I do not know why extra modules were not installed by dependency. When the Ubuntu fix is done I will return to this.

Comment: So you have checked on  5.4.0-65 without your dkms fix and it works

Comment: I didn't use my own dkms so I would know when the fix came.  I have been using kernels from proposed repos.  I am using the 5.4.0-66 now from normal repos and I didn't need my fix.  The bug caused an issue with cfg80211 and some other modules that cause ethernet to fail